# log4j configuration in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging, log4j, hql

I want to show sql queries executed by ihbernate in my logs.

This is my current log4j configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

 <appender name="CA" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>

 <root>
  <level value="info" />
  <appender-ref ref="CA" />
 </root>

<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
  <level value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="CA" />
 </logger>

 <logger name="org.hibernate.hql" additivity="false">
  <level value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="CA" />
 </logger>

 <logger name="org.hibernate.stat" additivity="false">
  <level value="trace" />
  <appender-ref ref="CA" />
 </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

But I am still getting nulls with `org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl`:

```
08-11-2016 09:54:39,318 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  - HHH000117: HQL: null, time: 1ms, rows: 4
```

How can I log full SQL instead of `HQL: null`?

Comment: have you enable <property name="show_sql">true</property> in your hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Yes. I have many sql logs but I am getting nulls only with DEBUG org.hibernate.stat.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl

Answer (score 0):

To log the executed queries I added the following to my logj4-configuration:

```
<!-- log Hibernate SQL Statements without parameters -->
 <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
<!-- add logging of parameters of the sql statements -->
<logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

Comment: removing `org.hibernate.stat` will switch off statistics logs. But I want to show SQL from those statistics not remove them!

Comment: Then you need this logger of course. I've updated my answer.